# Forming a basis of P3(R) from a set S.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I seem to have a good understanding of spanning sets and linear independence which then becomes essential for understanding basis, but I am unsure how all this works for the field of polynomials.

I know that P${_3}$($\mathbb{R}$) is the set of all polynomials degree less than or equal to 3.
Therefore it has a standard basis of $$\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$$

What I am having trouble with is understanding how to create a basis from a spanning set.

In my case the spanning set is $$S = \{ 1+2x , 1+x+x^2 , 2+x-x^2 , 3+2x , x-2x^3 \}$$

Because the standard basis has $x^3$ as an element, does this mean that $x-2x^3$ has to automatically be an element of the basis or am I going about this all wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, you say it correctly: a basis must certainly contain "all powers", so to speak. If you would take only elements which for example all don't have $x^3$, then you could never span the set. Now if you figure out which one of the elements in your spanning set is a linear combination of the others, you can take that one out and you should have a basis (if you had a spanning set to begin with).

Comment: So I have to, by definition, use the last vector in the set S and then find a combination of the others which will create a linear independent set?

Comment: Well yeah, the last one has to be in there. Then one of the other four can go. Any one which is a linear combo of the other 4 (but you already know that $x-2x^3$ won't do you any good because of the cubed power in there, so really of the other 3) has to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as you have said, you know that $S$ is a subspace of $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ (and may even be equal) and the dimension of $P_3(\mathbb{R}) = 4$. You know the only way to get to $x^3$ is from the last vector of the set, thus by default it is already linearly independent. Find the linear dependence in the rest of them and reduce the set to a linearly independent set, thus its own basis!

One way to find the linear independence might be to write them as column vectors in a matrix $A$ and row reduce.

Comment: And just to make sure I'm understanding everything, since the dimension is 4 for this polynomial, I have to find 4 polynomials from this set to create a basis?

Comment: Yes, if you wish to generate a basis for $P_3\mathbb{R}$